# Masking for Double and Integers in MVC4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mask

I am working in MVC4 Razor. For masking i am using "jquery.inputmask.js". I am facing following issue by using this :

**Problem**

**1.) Saving Integer with maxlength = 4 of input box (Integer type)**

If i insert all digits like 1231 then it is working fine but if i leave this field with partial fill then i am getting output like this 23___ when i click outside the input box input box become empty.

**2.)Saving Double with mask value "99.9" (Double type)**

In this case if i fill value like 08.9 and save it then i am getting output like 89._ which is invalid for double.

Before asking here i had done some homework and find out some links :

http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

How i can overcome these cases?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Name').focusin(function () {
                    $('#Name').mask("?99.99%");
                });
```

Add `?` and it resolved your problem.I am facing same situation and adding `?` first it

resolved this issue.

Demo :http://jsbin.com/UHOJopaY/1/edit

Comment: Currently i am using $("#Name").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "99.9" }); for masking where i have  to put your code ? Can you provide me fiddle so that i can test there also?

Comment: I also tested your code for case 1 :
Like
  $("#Name1").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "-9999" });
        $('#Name1').focusin(function () {
            $('#Name1').mask("?-9999%");
        });
still having the same issue

Comment: I am already using jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js in my project.Is <script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min_.js" will work with jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js ?

Comment: you have to use this script <script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min_.js"></script>  use this for mask and it;s working `jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min`